# Python imports after runtime installation of a depending package

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I'm installing a package ("A") at runtime with pip. Package B conditionally depends on A (doesn't 'require' it, except for certain uses).

My problem is this. My code, simplified, does this:

1. Install "A" at runtime.
2. Import B

   - When B is imported, B checks if A is installed like this:

> ```
> try:
>     import A
> except ImportError:
>     a = None
> def function():
>     if a is None:
>       raise ImportError("Can't import A!")
> ```

3. Call B.function()

---

What happens is:

> ImportError("Can't import A!")

I am not certain why this import error is thrown, since because A is installed before B is imported, A should be importable (or is this not correct?) Why might B be raising this error?

Thanks!

Comment: you need `except ImportError:` you left out a colon

Comment: try with "from A import B" might make sense......

Comment: Neither A nor B are my code.